# Having Trouble Insertring into a BST in Java

Tags: java

I'm working with text files that have long lists of words and inserting them into a binary tree. One text file I have is a list of words unsorted and it inserts perfectly fine into the BST. But the exact same word list in sorted form is giving me trouble. I keep getting a StackOverflowError from my insert function.

```
private TreeNode insert(TreeNode iter, String item) {
    if (iter == null) {
        iter = new TreeNode(item);
    } else {
        if (item.compareTo(iter.item) < 0 ) {
        iter.left = insert(iter.left, item);
        } else {
        iter.right = insert(iter.right, item);
        }
    }
    return(iter);
}
```

My theory is that since it's in order it will only call insert right causing it to somehow overflow. If anyone has any ideas how to fix this it would be wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

When you feed your BST a sorted list, all elements will be inserted on the same side (either all left or all right), depending on the sorting order. This causes your BST to become very high and unbalanced, causing very deep recursion, which will eventually result in StackOverflowError.

This is well known about BSTs in general. With shuffled values, the BST would be relatively balanced, with all branches having similar heights. With sorted values, the tree becomes unbalanced, and effectively work as a linked list. For a BST to be efficient, you need to keep it balanced.

One way to keep a BST balanced is using one of the [self-balancing implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), such as [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). A lazy workaround is to insert values shuffled. However, this latter does not guarantee that the BST will be balanced. In the worst extreme, the values can end up perfectly sorted after shuffling.